# AWS VPCとオンプレ間のVPN通信ができない

Tags: aws, vpn, vpc

表記にかかる質問をさせてください。
AWS VPCを構成し、オンプレ（自宅）に設置したvyosサーバ(VPN)間での通信が行えません。
現在実施していることは以下のとおりです。

前提　
　オンプレ側のネットワークは192.168.11.0/24、AWS側は192.168.12.0/24、192.168.13.0/24  → プライベートアドレスです。

[AWS側]
１　VPC
・専用のVPCを作成し、2つのCIDRブロックを設定（192.168.12.0/24、192.168.13.0/24）
・２つのサブネットを設定（192.168.12.0/24、192.168.13.0/24）
・ルートテーブルは以下のとおり。（ルート、ターゲット）
　　192.168.12.0/24 local
　　192.168.13.0/24 local
　　0.0.0.0/0 インターネットゲートウェイ
　　192.168.11.0/24 仮想プライベートゲートウェイ
・１つのインターネットゲートウェイを設定（VPCにアタッチ）
・ネットワークACLは以下のとおり
　　インバウンドルール　
　　　100 全てのトラフィック　全てのプロトコル　ソース　192.168.11.0/24 許可
　　　* デフォルトの拒否ルールです
　　アウトバウンドルール
　　　デフォルトのまま（0.0.0.0/24の許可と拒否が設定されているもの）
・セキュリティグループは以下のとおり。　→後述するEC2インスタンスに紐づけたもの
　　インバウンドルール
　　　すべての トラフィック　すべて　すべて　192.168.11.0/24
　　　すべての ICMP - IPv4 ICMP (1) すべて　::/0
　　アウトバウンドルール
　　　すべての トラフィック　すべて　すべて　0.0.0.0/0
・カスタマーゲートウェイ
　　VPCにアタッチし、BGPASNはデフォルトの65000
・仮想プライベートゲートウェイ
　　上記に紐づけて、AmazonASNはデフォルトの10124
・VPN接続
　　ルーティングはダイナミック、カスタマーGWアドレスは自宅のルータアドレス（インターネット側）

2 EC2
・EC2インスタンス（AmazonLinux)を立ち上げ、VPCにアタッチ。プライベートアドレスは192.168.12.10とした。（ElasitIPは不要なため設定なし）

[自宅側]
構成は以下のとおり。
デフォルトGW 自宅ルータ　192.168.11.1
VPNルータ（vyos）　192.168.11.2 eth1に設定し、NICは１つのみ
AWSVPCでダウンロードした設定を反映（set vpn ipsec site-to-site peerのローカルIPは192.168.11.2に変更）

上記設定を反映したところ、VPN(ipsec)は問題なく張られ、VPC側では問題なくUP状態になっています。また、VPCから見えるvpnトンネルのIP(外部アドレス)に対して、vyos（自宅）からpingを通すと問題なし。
しかし、EC2に対して、pingやSSH（AWS発行の鍵利用）を実行しても通信できない状態になっています。
Wiresharkでpingをモニタリングしたところ、vyosからAWS側の外部IPに対してESPで通信しているところはわかりますが、VPC側のフローログを確認しましたがログは拾えていない（届いていない）ようでした。

考えられる原因はなにかわかりますでしょうか。そもそもこの構成（VPNサーバ→自宅ルータ→インターネット→VPC→EC2)が正しく機能するのかをご教授ねがえますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

既に実施済みなのかもしれませんが、ルータ(192.168.11.1)で NATトラバーサルが必要なのではないでしょうか。
https://dev.classmethod.jp/etc/aws-vpc-vpn-nat-traversal/

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。再度確認してみたところ、当方のルータがNATトラバーサルに対応していないようです。（Buffaloのコンシューマ向け無線LANルータ）